# Filter value in java visualvm

Tags: visualvm, heap-dump

I'm trying to filter the String value, but it's not supported in VisualVM. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OQL to filter the strings. For example the following query will show strings containing 'AWT'

```
select s from java.lang.String s where s.toString().contains("AWT")
```

More information about OQL can found in [this](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/visualvm/visualvm.java.net.backup/master/www/oqlhelp.html) document.